# Как сделать кнопку при нажатии на которую появляется картинка React JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Доброго времени суток!

Новичок в этой сфере

Пробовал написать код, с помощью button и input но картинка просто не появляется. Также пытался найти решение в Google и на русском и на английском но просто не мог понять как работает код и как его правильно вставить и как все правильно подключить(я хочу расположить код в другой файле). Мне нужно несколько кнопок, при нажатии на которую появлялось изображение, а при нажатии на другую это изображение менялось на другое(желательно чтобы была анимация пролистывания по горизонтали в бок, но думаю что и так многого прошу). [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Вы изобрели табы)

Comment: @Summersby а при чем тут табы ?

Comment: ну погуглите что такое табы

Comment: @Summersby Огромное Спасибо. Несколько дней потратил, на написание кода для кнопки. Сначала подумал что ты имел ввиду отступ от края(TAB). Даже и не знал про эту Компоненту, еще раз спасибо

Comment: А зачем лесть в react,  не владея даже базово  js. Попробуйте получать картинку средствамт  js,  а уже потом можно и о  React  думать.

Comment: @WalkMess я владею JS на базовом уровне. Сначала сидел на leetcode решал разные задачки, у меня получалось но начало надоедать и решил изучить что-то новое. Сам не знаю почему, у меня не получилось написать такую простую функцию

Comment: @DAS https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hPfzI1-to6A

Answer (score -2, accepted):

вы можете писать это с нуля, но если надо быстро, то посмотрите в сторону готовых библиотек компонентов, где есть подобный функционал, вам лишь останется туда прокинуть данные(ну и правильно подключить либу). как пример:
https://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/menu/

проскрольте немного и увидите раздел Tabular